# Clean way to get my app version in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got a react-native app that I created by using `react-native init` and I'm trying to have like a global constant with my APP_VERSION so I can use it inside the Authentication/Login screen.

The only place I saw this variable is inside my package.json file.
After searching for this, seems that other people is trying to get it from here.
Although I wasn't that successful on doing it.

So the idea was to have a file like `src/_global/utils.js`

With this:

```
import * as pkg from '.package.json';

export const APP_VERSION = pkg.version;
```

But is throwing exceptions that module can't be resolved. Tried using require('.package.json'), didn't work either.

This is what the other method to get it looked like:

`var pkg = require('.package.json');`

Any way to get this version? Is there any other cleaner way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not importing your package.json correctly. You can also destructure it within the import.

```
import {name as app_name, version as app_version}  from './path/to/package.json';
```

Comment: Oh... damn, it worked... i attempted using the "correct" path and it wasn't letting me either, like this './../../package.json'. Thanks man! Seems that the destructure thing made it work for me.

Comment: Not entirely clear about how react-native handles it, but I have heard that in general you do not want to require for import anything from package.json in a website or app, because your package.json contains all the packages that a hacker can enumerate for vulnerabilities.

Comment: how can one read app version from package json .its to be read from android /app/build gradle

Answer (score 10):

You can use react native library

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
const appVersion = DeviceInfo.getVersion();

console.log("App Version",appVersion);
```

Comment: i'll try this out whenever possible, thanks for your help. The method mentioned above didnt work. I had compile errors at runtime. So yours might work.